# Show input text into div popup using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, popup

I want to show a popup which has the value of input text I already entered.

I want to receive the input data from bnumber input and show it into the popup. But below code doesn't contain the bnumber data.

[image]

My code shows

:[image]

But I want to show like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the script is running when the page is loading (and the input box is presumably empty), that's why you're not seeing the number in the popup. It looks like you're using jQuery Mobile popup. Assuming that's the case, you can listen to the `popupbeforeposition` event that fires right before a popup is rendered to the screen. You can use this event to take the current value from the input box and update the popup message...

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#popupDialog').bind({
        popupbeforeposition: function() {
            $('#po').html("<h3>Are you sure you want to cancel billing "
                           + $('#bnumber').val() + "?</h3>");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

[Documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0-rc.2/docs/pages/popup/events.html)